# Understanding caches and block sizes

Tags: caching, memory, block

A quick question to make sure I understand the concept behind a "block" and its usage with caches.

If I have a small cache that holds 4 blocks of 4 words each. Let's say its also directly mapped. If I try to access a word at memory address 2, would the block that contains words 0-3 be brought into the first block position of the cache or would it bring in words 2-5 instead?

I guess my question is how "blocks" exist in memory. When a value is accessed and a cache miss is trigger, does the CPU load one block's worth of data (4 words) starting at the accessed value in memory or does it calculate what block that word in memory is in and brings that block instead.

If this question is hard to understand, I can provide diagrams to what I'm trying to explain.

Answer (score 2):

Usually caches are organized into "cache lines" (or, as you put it, blocks). The contents of the cache need to be associatively addressed, ie, accessed by using some portion of the requested address (ie "lookup table key" if you will). If the cache uses a block size of 1 word, the entire address -- all N bits of it -- would be the "key". Each word would be accessible with the granularity just described.

However, this associative key matching process is very hardware intensive, and is the bottleneck in both design complexity (gates used) and speed (if you want to use fewer gates, you take a speed hit in the tradeoff). Certainly, at some point, you cannot minimize gate usage by trading off for speed (delay in accessing the desired element), because a cache's whole purpose is to be FAST!

So, the tradeoff is done a little differently. The cache is organized into blocks (cache "lines" or "rows"). Each block usually starts at some 2^N aligned boundary corresponding to the cache line size. For example, for a cache line of 128 bytes, the cache line key address will always have 0's in the bottom seven bits (2^7 = 128). This effectively eliminates 7 bits from the address match complexity we just mentioned earlier. On the other hand, the cache will read the entire cache line into the cache memory whenever any part of that cache line is "needed" due to a "cache miss" -- the address "key" is not found in the associative memory.

Now, it seems like, if you needed byte 126 in a 128-byte cache line, you'd be twiddling your thumbs for quite a while, waiting for that cache block to be read in. To accomodate that situation, the cache fill can take place starting with the "critical cache address" -- the word that the processor needs to complete the current fetch cycle. This allows the CPU to go on its merry way very quickly, while the cache control unit proceeds onward -- usually by reading data word by word in a modulo N fashion (where N is the cache line size) into the cache memory.

The old MPC5200 PowerPC data book gives a pretty good description of this kind of critical word cache fill ordering. I'm sure it's used elsewhere as well.

HTH... JoGusto.